# XSLT: Have ampersand in an input string, how to escape it

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT template. It is invoked and params are sent to it from a Java program.

The issue is, one of the variables contains an `'&'`.

```
<xsl:value-of select="customerName" />
```

customerName might contain an `'&'`. No matter what I do, I am unable to get it to render. I have tried

```
replace(customerName, '&', '&amp;')
```

Is there any way I can get this to render?

Comment: If `customerName` is a parameter, it should be `<xsl:value-of select="$customerName" />`. Note the `$`. You don't need to replace anything in Java.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You mention "an input string", "params" and "one of the variables" - but your stylesheet points to a node in the source document. If that's where the (unescaped) ampersand is, then your source document is not XML and cannot be procesed by XSLT. If it's in a parameter, then there shouldn't be any problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

So the input java parameter set contained a `&` and the output requires a `&amp;` maybe being XML too.

Then use the [output](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) element at the top to achieve this.

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

---

***Alternatives***

You could try to correct it on the **java** side too. Which when not working on `&` should function with the replacement `&amp;`.

```
customerName = customerName.replace(, "&", "&amp;");
```

In XSLT the following might just work.

```
replace($customerName, '&amp;', '&amp;amp;')
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this,

```
  <xsl:if test="contains($customerName,'&amp;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($customerName,'&amp;'),substring-after($customerName,'&amp;'))"/>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to remove it, he wants to render it.

Comment: Well he was using replace function of XSLT-2 that basically removes a character and places another in its place. Thats what I have done in a different way. Xml is basically used to carry data and since & is reserved character it needs to escaped or removed.

Answer (score 0):

To run XML in XSLT environment, XML should have standard entities, i.e., ISO entities, Unicode entities etc. are only allowed.

If '&' found then those strings should be end by ';' (Entity representation is &....;, i.e., entities should ends with semicolon as well those are should be defined entities)

Here '&' is not an entity, **'&amp;' or '&#x0026;'** is an entity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. 
Basically since the input parameter had an '&', it was invalid xml. I had to xml-encode it.

Comment: You answer is just as unclear as your question. An input **parameter** does not have to be valid XML. This is a technical issue - it's important to use precise terms.